# Custom search Wordpress doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, wordpress, search

A time ago (about an half year) I got a code to customize the searchpage of my customers' website/page [Tiantu-Mineralen Mineralen Gids](https://www.tiantu-mineralen.be/mineralen-a/). I made an copy of Wordpress' search page in my child-theme folder. Then, all the search results were displayed under eachother (Only title, thumbnail and the excerpt). Now, a few months later I search again (on 'ame'- for searching amethists), but I only got 1 result.

I tried to edit it myself but without success..
The code I have now is:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) { ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) { the_post(); ?>
        <div class="thumbsearch"><?php  the_post_thumbnail('small') ?></div>
        <div class="searchinfo"><h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php search_title_highlight(); ?>
        </a></h3>

        <?php echo substr(search_excerpt_highlight(),''); ?>
        <div class="h-readmore"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

I tried to delete:

```
 <?php echo substr(search_excerpt_highlight(),''); ?>
 <div class="h-readmore"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
```

I got more results, but it is very messed up.

My Custom Functions.php has the following code:

```
function search_excerpt_highlight( $limit ) {
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);

if ( count( $excerpt ) >= $limit ) {
    array_pop( $excerpt );
    $excerpt = implode(' ', $excerpt);
} else {
    $excerpt = implode(' ', $excerpt);
}

$excerpt = apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', $excerpt );

$allowed_tags = '<p>,<br>,<mark>';
$excerpt = strip_tags( $excerpt, $allowed_tags );

$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`', '', $excerpt);

$keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
$excerpt = trim(preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<mark class="search-
highlight">\0</mark>', $excerpt));

echo '<p>' . $excerpt . ' ...</p>';
}

function search_title_highlight() {
$title = get_the_title();
$keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
$title = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-
highlight">\0</strong>', $title);

echo $title;
}

function search_content_highlight($limit) {
    $content = get_the_content();
    $keys = implode('|', explode(' ', get_search_query()));
    $content = preg_replace('/(' . $keys .')/iu', '<strong class="search-
highlight">\0</strong>', $content);

    echo '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
}
```

Do you guys have a solution for this?!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: search seems to be working fine for me, and really as intended by wordpress.
It parses all the products for the search term, and produces results based on whether the search term is present in any of the titles or text inside the products and blogposts.

Comment: But how many results do you get? If I'm searching for 'ame' I just get 1 result instead of many more that need to be show up!

Comment: many, it depends on what keyword I am using.
when using "ame" I get 6 pages of results, when searching for "amethyst" I only get 2 products, and when searching for "amethist" I get 4 pages of results. Wordpress searched in both titles and content, keep that in mind

Comment: Yeah, I know.. I changed

    <?php echo substr(search_excerpt_highlight(),''); ?>

Into:

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

But the results don't line up very well..

Comment: ..and there are numbers in line 1 of the excerpt..

Comment: The strange thing is, I didn't change the code before..

Comment: Pasted a piece of code from my functions.php in the post above regarding the search results..maybe there is something wrong here?!